# List/Workflow Calculations set field and display updated results in real-time?

Tags: 2010, list, workflow

I have what I can only assume is such a basic issue that I am overcomplicating and that is why I can't seem to find a solution.

I have a list and want it to add two columns together and place the total in a third column. I can make a workflow to do this but for some reason I am unable to find a way to have the total display on the workflow. Nothing happens until the page is refreshed. This also leads to the potential problem of people changing numbers without the list refreshing and then getting conflicts.

Is there not a simple way to run basically the equivalent of a SUM function in Excel that is immediately (at least relatively) saved and updated in the list?

Update: Going to assume I can't comment because I had only set up a guest account initially. That may work if it updates in real-time. I'm surprised something so simple isn't... simpler. I was hoping to avoid getting into the code but nothing else seems to work so I'll give it a shot. Thank you for the response!

Comment: you mean calculated columns? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just embedding a Google spreadsheet using the following instructions and it was extremely easy to set up, supports formulas, support live updates to the data, and even has multiple tabs. Wish I had found that option a week ago!

http://googledrive.in30minutes.com/google-sheets-embed-live-spreadsheet/